# python twitter crawling_how can I extract tweet date or tweet time?

Tags: python, date, twitter, time, web-crawler

Now the code extracts only the content of the tweet.

ex: 13703 : {'text': 'RT @11111: hi hi hi hi hi~~'}

I want to extract the date(2017.04.16) or time(21:40) of tweet.Is it possible?

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'word1'
search_term2= 'word2'
search_term3='word3'

lat = "xxxx"
lon = "xxxx"
radius = "xxxx"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

API_key = "xxxx"
API_secret = "xxxx"
Access_token = "xxxx"
Access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bot [TwEater](https://github.com/mutux/TwEater) today on GitHub. It can collect all possible attributes of tweets, such as date, time, text, username, id, hashtags, mentions, links, even emojis, and the list of all its replies and so on. You can even get tweets earlier than past 7 days, no 3200 tweets limit. Go try it and have fun!